# How do I get sample values - Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I print this array with `var_export()`, How do I get sample values of "id", "username", "password", "livello" etc

```
array (
  'iss' => 'miosito.com',
  'aud' => 'loginutente',
  'iat' => 1651245629,
  'nbf' => 1651245639,
  'exp' => 1651288829,
  'data' => 
  (object) array(
     'id' => '6',
     'username' => 'testuser',
     'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
     'livello' => '1',
  ),
)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] - the exact code you ran, and the exact error it gave you.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing an object from within an array so `$arr['data']->id`

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, in the end I had found it!

Answer (score 0):

Since you converted the `data` array to an object, you can access the values like this

```php
echo $array['data']->id;
echo $array['data']->username;
...
```